# How to find original community description

Tags: support, site-description

Before joining a community you can easily see the community description. For example, for example before joining the Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange you see the description:

> Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange is a question and
>   answer site for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers.

However, after joining I can no longer see this description. I can go to the on-topic page and see a different description:

> Programming Puzzles & Code Golf is for programming contests and
>   challenges. We welcome questions from beginners and experts alike.

Yet, I cannot seem to find the original description anywhere. Is there a way to find the original description while being logged into a Stack Exchange site?

Based on Rene's answer, I can click the Tour link on each site, but StackOverflow (and maybe other sites) do not have a tour link. Instead, I'd have to go there by manually typing it in the address bar. Is there a reason that this has been removed from the Stack Overflow page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find that particular pay-off on the [tour](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour) which is reachable from the Help menu in the topbar.

On Stack Overflow the Tour didn't return in the topbar (and [Help only returned after some uproar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343228/578411)). Although the Help and Tour links can also be found in the footer of all sites, the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) didn't have that luck on Stack Overflow.  There it is simply missing. We can only guess for the reasons but style over function would be my bet.

To get to the Tour on Stack Overflow you have to take the tour to your addressbar and type the url yourself. Or leave a comment with `[tour]` in it as that will turn into a link as well when posted ...

Support [this Feature Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343663/578411) from [Travis J](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1026459/travis-j) to have it back.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Now, how do I find the tour link on sites such as Stack Overflow where there is no Help menu in the top bar? I can see the "tour" link in the source code, and can manually go to the address, but I cannot seem to find a link to that page.

Comment: In the new design on SO the `/tour` got [unlinked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343228/578411) totally and it didn't make it into the new footer either, as opposed to other sites, where the Tour is linked from the footer. What you see in the sourcecode is the *old* popup that is still present but has a CSS rule `display:none`

Answer (score 2):

You can always open any site in browser's private mode to see description that you saw before joining.

Comment: from all the options to get to the tour, I like this one best. It would be even more awesome when the tour only works in IE6 ... ;)

Comment: @rene strictly speaking my answer is not correct because OP want to see description *"while being logged into a Stack Exchange site"*

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. Well, my vote is locked now ...